# jQuery error after changed site server (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I just moved my site to another server and after that I have a jquery problem with a plugin. It doesn’t show the body and footer at the page where is the shortcode that shows the info. I re-installed but nothing changed. At the console it shows this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function    timetable.js:9

`timetable.js` works fine at the other server. This is the code of that line :

```
$(".tt_tabs").tabs({
    event: 'change',
    show: true,
    create: function(){
        $("html, body").scrollTop(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you missing af reference for the tabs plugin? Like this - <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Make sure you have jQuery UI as well as just jQuery - as jQuery UI is where the `.tabs()` comes from.

Comment: I'm not sure if there maybe be any different version of jquery at cpanel .

Comment: I'm having an identical issue.  Please follow up if you make any progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem.It was about the php version in server.It had been 5.3 and after I changed to 5.5 the plugin works ok now.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a header and a footer on the page you probably forgot to use them in your page. use `get_header(header);` function in PHP to get the header back and check if jQuery works after that.

Comment: the header is just fine 
Here are the URLs to my both sites :

1 http://www.salus.al/new/?page_id=9002 (with problem )

2 http://www.studentisot.al/saluss/?page_id=9002 (Thats ok)

Comment: At the first link your post 9002 does not have any content in it. so jquery cannot use timetable on the content

Comment: In that page is just an URL that excute a plugin.timetable is an other plugin that is in core of my theme.